# How do I extract text from string between underscores with mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need to derive a column based on text from another column. 
For instance, in the 'channel' column I have this text:

```
"RbkSEM_google_ecom-_-Branded-_-Core-_-Realdock"
```

I need to pull out "Branded" and put it into a column called 'derived_channel'

The positioning of the text I need to pull out will always be after the 3rd underscore and before the 4th underscore.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What if, in your example like, there are only 3 underscores?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following:

- table is called `mytable`
- column `channel` has `RbkSEM_google_ecom--Branded--Core-_-Realdock`
- you want to pull out `Branded` from between the `--` tokens
- place result in `derived_channel`

Here is your query

```
UPDATE mytable SET derived_channel = 
LEFT(SUBSTR(channel,LOCATE('--',channel)+LENGTH('--')),LOCATE('--',SUBSTR(channel,LOCATE('--',channel)+LENGTH('--'))) - 1);
```

Here is an example using user-defined variables

```
SET @st = 'RbkSEM_google_ecom--Branded--Core-_-Realdock';
SET @dm = '--';
SET @rv = LEFT(SUBSTR(@st,LOCATE(@dm,@st)+LENGTH(@dm)),LOCATE(@dm,SUBSTR(@st,LOCATE(@dm,@st)+LENGTH(@dm))) - 1);
SELECT @rv;
```

Here is the example executed

```
mysql> SET @st = 'RbkSEM_google_ecom--Branded--Core-_-Realdock';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @dm = '--';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @rv = LEFT(SUBSTR(@st,LOCATE(@dm,@st)+LENGTH(@dm)),LOCATE(@dm,SUBSTR(@st,LOCATE(@dm,@st)+LENGTH(@dm))) - 1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @rv;
+---------+
| @rv     |
+---------+
| Branded |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks Rolando . I realized the stackexchange editor change the _ to -. The values in the cells do not have --, so the query needs to be based on the position of the content relative to the number of underscores.

I updated my original question to reflect this.